# AWS Fargate: What does "duration" mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I need to make a make-or-buy decision when it comes to running docker containers. So I can either rent a dedicated server (aka root server) with one of the well-known companies and install Docker onto it myself or I might decide to use AWS Fargate.

Yet I fail to understand the pricing at AWS. Amazaon quotes a price per second, with a minimum of 1 minute and says that charging will start as soon as they start do download my Docker image.

That would suggest that if I would want to run any kind of web app on Fargate, then my monthly charges would be roughly 2,628e+6 * the price per second as I want my webapps to be available 7 x 24.

Just the example they make talks about apps running for 10 minutes each day. Who would want to run a website only 10 minutes each day?

I cannot help the feeling I don't get the concept here.

P.S.: I am aware of the other differences when it comes to hosting myself on a root server and hosting at AWS. This isn't what my question is about. I am trying to understand economics here. If I am about to run a dozend containers 7 x 24 I could easily rent two root servers for some 200 USD / month and had lots of spare capacity while at AWS I would easily end up paying 300, 400, 500 USD for my containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use cost is for active running tasks, not for the entire time it is "powered up."  That's how they calculated the examples on the page.  What I would recommend is that you use AWS calculators to determine your actual cost: a [TOC](https://cloud.netapp.com/tco-calculator) (total cost of ownership) and for a more complete picture AWS has their new monthly pricing calculator in beta now at http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html